# How to prevent afterimage when dragging

Tags: javascript, css

Implementing drag carousels.
When executing the mousemove event with the mouse, the drag is interrupted by the phenomenon shown in the image below

[image]

```css
img {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

Blocked as below, but text remains. How can I solve it?

The tags are organized as follows.

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href=""> // Moved to movie information page
      <img>
      </img>
      <p>movie name</p>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Add it to `img` tag, it will help.

UPD.

Another approach is to add  `draggable="false"` attribute to `img` and `a` tags.

Example here: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/kizersozzy/pen/vYroqjm)

Comment: Oh, thank you. However, this will block the href event of tag a. What should I do?

Comment: I have prepared an example for you, hope it helps:
[codepen](https://codepen.io/kizersozzy/pen/vYroqjm)

Answer (score 0):

Please check using this jquery code

```
$('img').on('dragstart', function(event) { event.preventDefault(); });
```

Note: Remember to import jquery in the header if you are not using it already.

Comment: Do they really need to import a large library just to do this one action? Pure JS should suffice.